# How can i increment a 16digit number by 1 to make 50 Million records

Tags: csv, awk, terminal

I have a CSV/txt file that i would like to increment by 1 to make 50 million records:

```
testfile.txt:
U|4100000000000001|21|01|CID1000001|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000002|21|01|CID1000002|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
```

Comment: you might also want to thing about what should happen when CID1000002 turns into CID9999999, what should the next record have? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one solution

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==1 {OFS=FS; p=substr($5,1,3); f5=substr($5,4)} 
                   {while(i++<10) {print; ++$2; $5=p (++f5)}}' file

U|4100000000000001|21|01|CID1000001|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000002|21|01|CID1000002|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000003|21|01|CID1000003|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000004|21|01|CID1000004|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000005|21|01|CID1000005|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000006|21|01|CID1000006|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000007|21|01|CID1000007|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000008|21|01|CID1000008|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000009|21|01|CID1000009|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
```

notice that the fifth field length may change after 10M as commented by @shellter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` that should do, just change `5` with `50000000`

```
cat file
U|4100000000000001|21|01|CID1000001|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE

awk -F'|' '{OFS=FS;a=$2;split($5,b,"D");for(i=0;i<5;i++){$2=a+i;$5="CID"b[2]+i;print}}' file
U|4100000000000001|21|01|CID1000001|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000002|21|01|CID1000002|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000003|21|01|CID1000003|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000004|21|01|CID1000004|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
U|4100000000000005|21|01|CID1000005|PULL_TEST|ACTIVE
```

Comment: Have another one here:

```U|DID1000001|CID1000001|John|Smith|SMS|1212
U|DID1000002|CID1000002|Joe|Doe|SMS|1212```